# I heard this sentence in the movie "the king 2019" and i want to know if the word elapsed an adjective or not

Tags: adjectives

you should be amply equipped to penetrate the fog of time **elapsed**.
is the word elapsed an adjective ?

Comment: See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+time+elapsed%2Cof+time+passed%2Cof+time+past&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10), showing that ***time elapsed, time passed,*** and ***time past*** have all been about equally common for centuries. So far as I'm concerned, for most purposes they're syntactically and semantically much the same. Except ***past*** refers to an actual time ***before now***, whereas the other two refer to the ***passage of time*** in the abstract.

Comment: Have I answered? Is an answered question an example of an adjectival usage?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I hope this comment makes your last a question answered.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm afraid this doesn't answer my question

Comment: Yes, it's an adjective. A participial adjective.

Comment: Bol123, what research have you done?

Comment: So it ***is*** an answered question!

Comment: It can't be anything else. It modifies elapsed and "of" is followed by a noun phrase, such as a noun with an adjectival modifier.